# Can these equations be considered as differential equations?

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Consider a differential equation with  a term containing $y(x_0)$, for example $$y'' - 2y' + y = y(x_0)$$ $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$ is a constant. My question is, does such equations fall under the category of differential equations? I have never studied any equation with such a term. If its a differential equation, then $y(x_0)$ can be considered a constant coefficient?

Comment: There could be multiple terms like $y(x_0), y(x_1),y(x_2)$ too.

Comment: But $y(x_0)$ is assumed to be a constant.

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner : it is not independent of $y$. It depends on the solution.

Comment: Think that $y(x_0) =\int \delta(x-x_0) y(x) dx$. After that you can solve the linear DE using the Laplace Transform.

Comment: @Cesareo : differential equations with distributions? Any theory available on this?

Comment: I remember seeing such kind of a distribution term as impulse in the field control theory

Answer (score 0):

Although the term $y(x_0)$ depends on the solution $y$ it is still a constant as it doesn't depend on $x$.

Let's try to solve your equation $y'' - 2y' + y = C,$ where $C=y(x_0).$ One solution is $y(x) = C.$ The solutions of the homogeneous equation are $y(x) = (Ax+B) e^x.$ Therefore the general solutions are
$$y(x) = (Ax+B) e^x + C.$$

To get $y(x_0) = C$ we must have $A=B=0.$ Thus there is only the constant solution
$$y(x) = C = y(x_0).$$

Comment: You can also have constants $A, B$ with $Ax_0+B=0$ so that the general solution is $$y(x) = A(x-x_0)e^x+B$$ (replaced $C$ with $B$).